# How to install edgeR package using R4.2.0, BiocManager?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I tried to install edgeR with the following:

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)); install.packages("BiocManager"; BiocManager::install("edgeR")
```

This is the message I got

> Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
> Installing package(s) 'edgeR' Warning: unable to access index for
> repository
> https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/bioc/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
> cannot open URL
> 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/bioc/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository
> https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/annotation/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
> cannot open URL
> 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/annotation/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository
> https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/experiment/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
> cannot open URL
> 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/experiment/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository
> https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/workflows/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
> cannot open URL
> 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/workflows/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository
> https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/books/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2:
> cannot open URL
> 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/books/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES'
> Package which is only available in source form, and may need
> compilation of   C/C++/Fortran: ‘edgeR’

Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel)

so I pressed yes, then,i got the warning message

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0/12.0.1'
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib' ld: library not found for -lgfortran
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation) make: *** [edgeR.so] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for
> package ‘edgeR’
>
> - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/edgeR’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/private/var/folders/kt/6_fbqvnx7p94hxygb7x6qbnc0000gr/T/RtmpG39FBI/downloaded_packages’
> Warning message: In install.packages(...) :   installation of package
> ‘edgeR’ had non-zero exit status

Please advise on what I should to fix this problem.

Comment: Did you try a web search with error message? I’m not sure of your particular error, but it refers to fortran. Maybe your Mac is missing a fortran library? Maybe add a “Mac” or “apple” tag your question? I’m not saying it’s the cause, but maybe someone with Mac insights will come across the question and have better help.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for getting back to me! I spent a few more hours searching the internet, and it seems like it was the Mac problem. After I installed the right format of R (intel) version, BiocManager works in my Mac M1 now.

Comment: I'm glad that you got the problem solved. I would suggest maybe writing the explicit steps of what you did into answer (scroll below the comments) and then you can mark the answer accepted. It's okay to answer your own question as long as you have made your answer clear enough that another user who comes looking for help to the same question can repeat your steps. Like explicit system paths you used for example or including a particular argument in a command/function. Then click the big check next to your answer to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a Macbook pro (Monterey) M1 user, I re-installed R package (R-4.2.0.pkg), and removed the old package (R-4.2.0-arm64.pkg). This allowed me to use BiocManager to install other packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on an Apple Silicon Mac. I had assorted previous R installs via homebrew and others. Removing all existing R installations (check via Terminal with 'which R') then reinstalling from a fresh download of the arm64 build did the trick.